# Is this a valid case to use instanceof operator?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, instanceof

I am a beginner in Java and OOP in general, and I have a question regarding inheritance in Java.

In my project, I have a class `Order` that represents a order placed for an asset. I intend to have several classes that extend `Order` including `LimitBuyOrder` and `LimitSellOrder` & the likewise for market orders.

I will also have a class `Position`, which consists of a pair of orders. In order to determine the kind of `Position`, I must know which type of `Order` was entered first. Although the `instanceof` operator would work in this situation, I feel it is not an appropriate solution. Below is a stripped-down snippet, which may help to illustrate my problem:

```
class Position {
    //Other fields and methods omitted for clarity
    public void open(Order o) {
        if(o instanceof LimitBuyOrder)
            //Set position type to LONG
        if(o instanceof LimitSellOrder)
            //Set position type to SHORT
    }
}
```

Or should I do something like define methods in `Order` such as `isLimitBuy()` & etc, which return `false` and override them to return `true` based on which subclass `Order` is extended by?

```
class Position {
    //Other fields and methods omitted for clarity
    public void open(Order o) {
        if(o.isLimitBuyOrder())
            //Set position type to LONG
        if(o.isLimitSellOrder())
            //Set position type to SHORT
    }
}
```

Basically, my question is how do I determine the type of a subclass properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you are suggesting would work, but if it is only going to be used in the `open` method then what you have is also OK.

Comment: Why not delegate the behavior to the `Order` interface? I would try to limit the number of `instanceof`(s), if you **must** determine if something is assignable you could use [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with using `instanceof` in the manner above, but generally "O-O design" will lead one to want to have an attribute of Order provides the equivalent info.  IOW, if this were the *only* place where you needed to tell the difference then `instanceof` is probably a good idea, but if there are other situations where you need type-specific info or actions then you should consider utilizing the power of O-O.

Comment: These approaches aren't *wrong*, per se, but they're not OO.  If you use the `instanceof` approach, you have to add a new `if` clause every time you add a new `Order` type.  And if you do it the second way, you have to do that *plus* add a new `isXyzOrder()` method to every existing `Order` type.  Derek Hulley's answer shows the polymorphic, OO way.  If you do it the OO way, adding a new `Order` type won't affect anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should aim to encapsulate the *behaviour* within the types of orders rather than simply using their types externally to switch behaviour.

Add a method to your 'Order' class that does the work and then you do not have to know what type it is at all:

```
order.openPosition(...);
```

Let the 'Order' do whatever it needs to do according to its type.

A significant benefit to encapsulation is that you end up having all the order-type-specific behaviour in one place.  Abstract parent classes come naturally to provide any common order characteristics.  With the code in one place (or at least in a small hierarchy of classes) you can change the behaviour without having to visit code all over your application.

Comment: Well stated. 1+ Deleting my answer in favor of this one.

Comment: You should mention that this is an example of *polymorphism*.

Comment: Although OOP still kinda makes my head spin, this answer makes sense. This way I don't need to worry about the types of the `Order`. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: quite shocked that OP's username was somehow not taken